# Intellij Tool : What is the short cut for auto import all java classes at one go?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For example:-

```
LocalDate.now();
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(".");
CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> System.out.println("bingo"));
```

I can auto import class by moving pointer to respective class and click alt + enter, has to do same process for all classes. Is there any command that helps auto import all classes at one go?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the settings on your intelliJ.

Got to: Preferances --> Editor --> General --> Auto imports then make sure that the 'Add unambiguous imports on the fly' checkbox is checked.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks

Comment: Do accept the answer if you get a solution from that. @bshr

Answer (score 0):

In intellij, Go to **File** -> **Settings** -> **Editor** -> **General** -> **Auto import** -> Enable **Add unambiguous imports on the fly** -> Click on **Apply** -> **OK**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Import IntelliJ imports shortcut for Mac**

```
Shift + Alt + Enter
```